# jack audio program with multiple outputs gives ardour huge cpu loads when connected

Tags: c, linux, sdl, signal-processing, jack

I am creating a music software using jack, that has multiple outputs (16). When running full dsp process in my program (many synths, samplers, etc..), the cpu load is little high but nothing near troubling. This is when jack client's outputs are unconnected or connected straight to sound card outputs.

So, then as I start Ardour and open empty template (no plugins or anything), cpu load stays down in 5% (monitoring with top) until I connect my program's outputs into Ardour inputs. After that, Ardour cpu usage jumps to 80-95% and causes everything to slow down into unusable, even if my prog is not processing much anything. This doesn't make any sense as puredata instances with the same or higher amount of jack outputs are not causing similar cpu loads to ardour (empty or even full with plugins).

In my program, all outputs are processed in the same jack callback function, is this the correct way of doing it for multiout ? What could be causing this cpu peak ? I am using rt kernel on linux test machine and my program's gui is drawn with SDL.

It is starting to be very cool program, but this problem makes it kinda unusable.

Comment: Please supply code illustrating the problem you're experiencing

Comment: For performance you should try to run it in a profiler... If you are using SDL 1.3 and the graphics are intensive, that could be the reason as SDL1.3 uses software rendering afaik

Comment: You did try connecting to something other than Ardour for comparison? If it's only Ardour causing trouble, perhaps best ask [Ardour Forums](https://community.ardour.org/forums) directly.

Comment: Graphics (SDL 1.2) are very minimal and run perfectly fine without ardour connection. As for other jack connections, routing 12 outputs of the program into audacity and recording all, does not cause any cpu peak. I'll try Ardour forum..

Comment: Ok, solved this problem with a help from ardour developer. My program was producing denormal floats somewhere in the dsp code that caused this behaviour. Disabling denormal floats with SSE instrucion removed the high cpu load entirely.